# Sorting items by common elements

Tags: python, maya

The title is a little abstracted but I think it's accurate to what I'm looking for.
Specifically given a list of polygon edges, group all edges which are connected by a vertex.

I know this should be a simple issue, but I keep finding the wrong solution.

example input:

```
looseComponents = cmds.ls(sl=True, fl=True)
# Result: [u'pCube1.e[3]', u'pCube1.e[6]'] #
```

Getting output:

```
found 2 component sets
[u'pCube1.e[3]']
[u'pCube1.e[3]']
```

Expected ouput:

```
found 2 component sets
[u'pCube1.e[3]']
[u'pCube1.e[6]']
```

This is what I have at the moment, it's runs in Maya, written in Python.

```
looseComponents = cmds.ls(sl=True, fl=True)

#build sub item lookup
componentVerts = {}
for component in looseComponents:
    verts = cmds.ls(cmds.polyListComponentConversion(component, toVertex=True), fl=True)
    vertIds = []
    for vert in verts:
        i = int( vert.split('[')[-1].strip(']'))
        vertIds.append(i)
    componentVerts[component] = set(vertIds)

sortedComponents = 0
totalComponents = len(looseComponents)
componentSets = [ [] ]
componentSets[0].append( looseComponents[0] )
sortedComponents += 1

while sortedComponents < totalComponents:
    # for each subSetA of setA
    foundConnectingSet = False
    for i in range(len(componentSets)):
        # for each itemA of subSetA
        for j in range(len(componentSets[i])):
            # for each itemB of setB
            for h in range(len(looseComponents)):
                # check if itemA and itemB share a sub item
                if componentVerts[componentSets[i][j]] & componentVerts[looseComponents[h]]:
                    # if itemB isn't already part of this subSetA
                    if looseComponents[h] not in componentSets[i]:
                        # add itemB to this subSetA
                        componentSets[i].append(looseComponents[h])
                        sortedComponents += 1
                        foundConnectingSet = True

    if not foundConnectingSet:
        starter = looseComponents[0]
        for i in range(len(componentSets)):
            looseComponents = list( set(looseComponents) - set(componentSets[i]))
        componentSets.append( [ starter ] )         
        sortedComponents += 1

print 'found ' +str(len(componentSets))+ ' component sets'
for componentSet in componentSets:
    cmds.confirmDialog()
    cmds.select(componentSet, replace=True)
    print cmds.ls(sl=True)
```

With one edge selected I get one set.
With two unconnected edges selected I get two sets but both sets have the same edge in them.

Comment: Note that when doing `for i in range(len(foo))`, you could also do `for i,_ in enumerate(foo)`.

Comment: How is this "sorting"? I think it's more correct to say that you are classifying the polygons. Also, without the output you are getting and the expected output that you would like to obtain it's hard to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: true, editing the post to adding example input, output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

well, I got one solution to work consistently.

```
looseComponents = cmds.ls(sl=True, fl=True)

totalComponents = len( looseComponents )
sortedComponents = 0    
componentSets = []

vertComponent = {}
componentVert = {}
for component in looseComponents:
    verts = cmds.ls(cmds.polyListComponentConversion(component, toVertex=True), fl=True)
    for vert in verts:
        if vert in vertComponent:
            vertComponent[vert].append(component)
        else:
            vertComponent[vert] = [component]
    componentVert[component] = verts

def getConnectedComponent(component):
    verts = componentVert[component]
    connections = []
    for vert in verts:
        connections.extend( vertComponent[vert] )
    return list(set(connections) - set([component]))

def getRemainingComponent():
    remainingComponents = looseComponents
    for componentSet in componentSets:
        remainingComponents = list(set(remainingComponents)-set(componentSet))
    if remainingComponents:
        return remainingComponents[0]
    else:
        return None

while sortedComponents < totalComponents:
    component = getRemainingComponent()
    if component:
        componentSets.append( [component] )
        sortedComponents += 1
    connections = getConnectedComponent(component)
    while set(connections) - set(componentSets[-1]):
        newConnections = list( set(connections) - set(componentSets[-1]) )
        componentSets[-1].extend( newConnections )
        sortedComponents += len(newConnections)
        connections = []
        for component in newConnections:
            connections.extend( getConnectedComponent(component) )

print 'found ' +str(len(componentSets))+ ' component sets'
for componentSet in componentSets:
    cmds.confirmDialog()
    cmds.select(componentSet, replace=True)
    print cmds.ls(sl=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I tend to harp pymel on here quite a bit but it's just so painful to watch everyone go through the hassle of cmds. If you aren't obligated to them, the alternative would be this:

```
from pymel.core import *

verts = [i for i in polyCube()[0].vtx]

for j in verts:
    print "{0} is connected to {1}".format(j, j.connectedEdges())
```

It's much more fluid when it's object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

i'd just try it by making a dictionary out of all the verts converted to edges:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def vert_edge_map(obj):
    verts = cmds.polyEvaluate(obj, v=True)
    mapping = {}
    for r in range(0, verts):
        edges = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(obj + ".vtx[%i]" % r, fv=True, te=True)
        edges = cmds.filterExpand(edges, sm=32)
        mapping[r] = set(edges)
    return mapping

vert_edge_map('pCube1')
# Result: {0: set([u'pCube1.e[4]', u'pCube1.e[0]', u'pCube1.e[10]']), 1: set([u'pCube1.e[0]', u'pCube1.e[11]', u'pCube1.e[5]']), 2: set([u'pCube1.e[4]', u'pCube1.e[1]', u'pCube1.e[6]']), 3: set([u'pCube1.e[1]', u'pCube1.e[7]', u'pCube1.e[5]']), 4: set([u'pCube1.e[2]', u'pCube1.e[8]', u'pCube1.e[6]']), 5: set([u'pCube1.e[2]', u'pCube1.e[9]', u'pCube1.e[7]']), 6: set([u'pCube1.e[3]', u'pCube1.e[8]', u'pCube1.e[10]']), 7: set([u'pCube1.e[3]', u'pCube1.e[9]', u'pCube1.e[11]'])} #
```

All the values are sets, so you can test to see if two verts are connected by in intersecting the two vert's sets:

```
def are_connected(v1, v2, mapping):
    return len(mapping[v1].intersection(mapping[v2])) > 0
```

and create islands of connected stuff with unions:

```
def lots_of_edges(mapping, *verts):
   result = set()
   for v in verts:
       result = result.union(mapping[v])
   return result
```